# RQ / LQ / QL of general matrices implementation in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, function-construction, programming

Does anyone know if there are Mathematica implementations for the [*LAPACK routines*](https://www.smcm.iqfr.csic.es/docs/intel/mkl/mkl_manual/lse/lse_crofactor.htm) RQ, LQ and QL factorizations for general sized matrices?

It would even be great if the RQ factorization allowed a user to select that the diagonal elements of $R$ are positive, for example. Here is an example of the general and $3\times 3$ variant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640695/rq-decomposition.

I have searched the web, function repository and this Stack Exchange but no luck so far and calling LAPACK directly is kludgy.

Comment: Your link shows how to get RQ from QR. It is easy to get LQ from QR: Do `{qqt,rrt}=QRDecomposition[Transpose[mat]]` and then `{qq,ll}=Map[Transpose,{qqt,rrt}]`.